# Why SVN merges changes on checkin instead of replacing?

Tags: svn, version-control

I was just told that if I make change in a file and then check-in (I use Visual Studio + Ankh) then the changes will be effectively merged. I always thought that whatever I check in - its ultimate. I was sure the files I check in will be replaced in its entirety, keeping the source 100% up to date. No tampering..

Now I hear svn in fact merges files at the repo.. Is this correct?

If yes - what other source control systems do in this matter? Git, MS TFS?

Comment: You were told wrong. Read the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com), so you'll learn how it works. (And don't believe everything you're told.)

Comment: yep, I confronted the person who told me that (cos he is my boss in a sense) and asked to do changes from 2 accounts in a same file and it didn't work - SVN didn't let me check-in unless I update it locally first.. So yes - there is no merge. If you put your comment for answer I just mark it.

Comment: I think you're confusing *merging* with *change deltas*. When you check in a file, SVN doesn't store a whole new copy of the file; it  stores only the parts that were changed between the last revision and the one you're checking in (the differences are the *change deltas*). *Merging* refers to taking two copies that contain different changes and figuring out (automatically or with developer help) how to add all of those changes to the file that is in the repository to create a new single revision. Once again, read the book I linked - it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told wrong. Merging happens in your working copy and not during the commit.  Almost all version control systems do it this way: Merges take place in the developer's working area, and the changes that are committed is exactly what was in the developer's working area.

Imagine a scenario where your coworker and you checkout the same file. Your coworker initializes a counter variable in line #90 of the program and does some counting between lines #91 and #110. Somewhere around line #200, your coworker uses the count stored in this variable. Meanwhile, you decide to use that same counter variable in lines #150 and #175.

When a merge takes place, it will not have any conflicts. You changed different lines than your coworker. However, you can see that there are *logic conflicts* even if there are no *line conflicts*.

This is why a merge has to take place in a working copy. It's up to that developer who owns that working copy to verify that there is no problems with the merge. After all, when that developer does their merge in their working copy, their name will be on that change when they do their commit.

---

> yeah i know that.. my boss was convinced otherwise :)

## Proof: The less a manager knows, the more money they make

#### According to Physics:

> `Power = Work / Time`

#### According to your boss:

> `Time = Money`

#### So we substitute

> `Power = Work / Money`

#### According to Machivelli:

> `Knowledge = Power`

#### So we substitute once again:

> `Knowledge = Work / Money`

#### We can restate this to solve for Money:

> `Money = Work / Knowledge`

As `Knowledge` approaches zero, `Money` increases regardless of the amount of `Work`.

Comment: yeah i know that.. my boss was convinced otherwise :)

Comment: There's an equation for that. See appended above.

Comment: yeah I know I am not new in this business :) unfortunately I like what I do.. So I probably will never be the boss :)